# Java assigning a two-dimensional arrayto a three-dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays

I have the following code which seems to compile:

```
int[] arr = {1, 2};
int[][] arr2 = {arr, {1, 2}, arr};
int[][][] arr3 = {arr2};
```

Could you please explain why the last statement works? Don't we assign a two-dimensional array to a three-dimensional array here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Don't we assign a two-dimensional array to a three-dimensional array here?

You are correct if you do this

```
   int[][][] arr3 = arr2;
```

But what you are doing here `int[][][] arr3 = {arr2};` is not assigning. You are creating array with an element inside it.

Adding an element and assigning the references are 2 different things.

That works because in your array called `arr3` you have a 2D array at row zero and column zero which is fine.

Inshort

```
int[][][] arr3 = {arr2};
```

is equals to

```
int[][][] arr3 = new int[10][10][10];
arr3[0] = arr2;
```